# How to insert into POSTGRESQL table mac-address from string value

Tags: postgresql, freepascal, lazarus, mac-address

I use a table with mac-address field.
Now I want to create an insert statement to insert mac address from my edit.

SQL Insert:

```pascal
cInsertL2IfParams    : string = 'INSERT INTO tb_macaddresses(fmacaddr) ' +
                            'VALUES(pMyMACAddress::macaddr)';
```

So:

```pascal
mymacaddr := MainDM.MainSQLQ.Params.CreateParam(TFieldType.ftString,'pMyMACAddress',TParamType.ptInput);
mymacaddr.value := myedit.Text;

"Open" procedure rised exception: EPQDatabaseError... ...string contains NULL (10,null)
SQL State: 23502
...
```

I try to insert my string in the pgAdmin and I don't have any error:

```sql
INSERT INTO tb_macaddresses(fmacaddr)
VALUES('18:FD:74:7F:73:D3'::macaddr);
```

Comment: my insert query is: cInsertL2IfParams    : string = 'INSERT INTO tb_macaddresses(fmacaddr)                             VALUES(:pMyMACAddress::macaddr)';

Answer (score 1):

Found temporary variant. I removed TParam and insert ordinary text.

```
MainDM.MainSQLQ.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO tb_netifl2params(tb_netif_id, tb_netifl2params_mac, tb_netifl2params_adminmac) VALUES(:pL2NetIfID,' + '''' + edL2InterfaceMAC.Text + '''' + ',' + '''' + edL2AdminMAC.Text + '''' + ')';
```

`tb_netifl2params_mac` and `tb_netifl2params_adminmac` are MAC-address fields.
`edL2InterfaceMAC.Text` and `edL2AdminMAC.Text` string values from `TEdit`.